# Using \frak with context

Tags: fonts, context

I am trying context out and cannot get `\frak` to work.

Should the following work?

```
\starttext
{\frak The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 1234567890}
\stoptext
```

I did a cut and paste of the `{\frak}` line from http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/frak.

I also tried the braces like `\frak{text}` but to no avail.

Comment: Seems to work with ConTeXt MkII (`pdflatex`), but not with MkIV (`lualatex`), unless you're in math mode..

Comment: As @torbjorn-t says, in MkIV ``\frak`` will only have an effect in math mode since it [tests for math mode explicitly](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/math-ini.mkiv#l208).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point during the move from Pdftex to Luatex Context dropped
support for the “old way” of handling parts of math typesetting.
Font processing nowadays
[relies heavily on Luatex attributes](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/math-map.lua#l559),
some
of which Context only considers in math mode.
Thus some control sequences that used to be font switches in the Pdftex
era are today mapped to Lua code that just doesn’t execute outside
math.
Take for example this demonstration:

```
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161639/14066
%% run with MkII or MkIV
\def \demo {\fontname \font: \hskip \emwidth ABC abc 42}
\def \test #1{%
  \section {\detokenize {#1}}%
  \doifmodeelse {mkiv} {
    %% This works in MkIV …
    \startmathmode
      #1 \demo
    \stopmathmode
  } {
    %% … but this has an effect only in MkII.
    #1 \demo
  }
  \endgraf
}
\starttext
  \test \frak
  \test {\doifmodeelse{mkiv}\gothic\goth} %% no “goth” synonym in MkIV
  \test \cal
  \test \bbd
\stoptext
```

The MkIV part of the conditional will lose its effect if the enclosing
`mathmode` environment is commented out; the font remains unchanged.

The actual macros used to be defined in
[`font-ini.mkii`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/font-ini.mkii#l3110),
but were moved to the more specific
[`math-ini.mkiv`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/math-ini.mkiv#l208)
in MkIV.
As is obvious from the definitions:

```
...
\unexpanded\def\frak      {\ifmmode\expandafter\mathfraktur   \fi}
\unexpanded\def\cal       {\ifmmode\expandafter\mathscript    \fi}
\unexpanded\def\bbd       {\ifmmode\expandafter\mathblackboard\fi}
\unexpanded\def\blackboard{\ifmmode\expandafter\mathblackboard\fi}
\unexpanded\def\fraktur   {\ifmmode\expandafter\mathfraktur   \fi}
\unexpanded\def\gothic    {\ifmmode\expandafter\mathfraktur   \fi}
  ...
```

they won’t do anything outside math mode.
Btw. those conditionals are there for perfomance reasons only since
calling `\mathfraktur` and the likes outside math modes has no effect
to begin with.

However, the new order of things doesn’t prevent you from loading the
exact same fonts that would have been used by Pdftex.
You can just define them like any other font:

```
\def \demo {\fontname \font: \hskip \emwidth ABC abc 42}

\definefont [frakturfont]      [eufm10 at 20pt]
\definefont [calligraphicfont] [msbm10 at 20pt]

\setupbodyfont [20pt]

\def \othertest #1{
  \section {\detokenize {#1}}
  \begingroup #1\demo \endgroup \endgraf
}

\starttext
  \othertest \frakturfont
  \othertest \calligraphicfont
\stoptext
```

[image: output of above commands]